# Datepicker partially hidden by overflow-y scroll

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, overflow

[image]

I am building a bootstrap-grid column inside of which I have a panel.

Inside this panel I have a datepicker and there must a lot of other controls so I would need to be able to scroll down (y-axis only) inside the panel.

Unfortunately the datepicker popup window is partially hidden because of the overflow-z and overflow-x styling which enables the scrolling :

```
<div style="height: 480px;overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x:hidden;">
...
</div>
```

Is it possible to overcome this with some CSS trick?

I have found an answer on SO when the element poping out can be placed outside of the div but in my case I'm using a directive from the Angular-strap library so I need to place it inside.

I have set up a plunker to illustrate the issue (you need full-view to see it) : [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LxvOb4bNXdJVBwNu0h1n?p=preview)

Comment: popup looks good to me

Comment: @JordanD Did you open the full-screen view?

Comment: Yes, nothing overflows

Comment: @JordanD Weird.. I have tried on Mac, PC, Chrome, Firefox, the popup is partially hidden. It occurs on the right when the input is narrower than the popup. I will try to upload a screen capture.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, since no one bothered to answer, I just found the answer today, which was actually very simple.

I just needed to add this in the attributes :

```
data-container="body"
```

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3UHt9e7RGaxptdj1kHAa?p=preview)

Comment: Awesome, actually what i was looking for :)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Will this work for bootstrap datetimepicker? because I could not apply this approach there.

Comment: Sorry I can't tell you. I'm using a custom datepicker now.